# How does a fibre's gain influence the performance of an etalon in wavelength selection?

Tags: optics, fiber-optics, photonics

I performed an experiment using a YDF laser and aimed to tune it. 
A prism was used to refract the output light from the laser and a mirror was used to reflect back a specific wavelength.

It lased, but the width of the lasing peak (as seen in the spectrometry) was a bit too wide (10nm) and in order to try to decrease it an etalon was placed in between the fibre and the prism.

My lecturer says that "it was too much gain for the etalon and it won't work on that fibre".
I don't understand how the gain of a fibre can affect the etalon's performance.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm guessing the etalon reflects too much light (or maybe too little) back into the fiber?  The "mirror" you used must have been designed to have certain amount of transmission/reflection .. so that light can come out but enough goes back in to keep the lasing going.

Comment: Thank you, that might be it, I sure hope so.